# Unity Collision Plane Causing issues with physics simulation

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, collision

I am using a golf course asset and was having trouble when the ball would come into contact with the mesh surrounding the hole as. I am not exactly sure how to fix this. I have attached a screenshot showing the mesh and the projected path of the ball. Can someone help me out here? (incase image didn't load: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ygzj.jpg)

Comment: What's the "trouble"?

Comment: The fact that I want the ball to roll like a normal ball would and not have random physics when coming into contact with those regions of the mesh

Comment: you need to explain the problem in more detail. "was having trouble when the ball would come into contact with the mesh surrounding the hole" does not explain the problem

Comment: I’m a very beginner level unity developer and am not sure on how else to put the question forward. When I tried debugging the error (the ball randomly jumping) I saw the wireframe and thought the issue is coming due to this. Does this not sound like something that could be the cause of such an issue?

Comment: seems the ball "randomly" jumps when you arrive to the hole, that a bit better explained. Seems your hole mesh might be having a meshcollider, so that when the ball arrives, it jumps. Try check if the hole gameobject has any collider and deactivate or remove it

Comment: for more accurate help, explain the problem in detail, how is it produced, what is the expected outcome, what is the obtained outcome and your involved gameObject components